# How can the polar form of a complex number be$ r(\cos(x)-i\sin(x))$?

Tags: complex-numbers

I don't understand how this can form can work: $r(\cos(x)-i\sin(x))$. I saw it in my textbook. Surely there should be a "$+$" rather than a "$-$" between the $\cos$ and the $\sin$. If the imaginary part was negative then surely that would be accounted for by the argument which in this case I have written as "$x$".

Comment: you are right, it should be $+$

Comment: Perhaps they were writing $\bar z$, the complex conjugate of $z$?

Comment: You can write a complex number either as $r(\cos x - i \sin x)$ or as $r(\cos\theta + i \sin\theta)$, simply by substituting $x=-\theta$.

Comment: Where in what book?

Comment: IF you gave an exact quote from the textbook, including context, we might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use the fact that $-\sin (x) = \sin (-x)$ and $\cos (x) = \cos (-x)$, then your expression becomes $r(\cos (-x) + i \sin (-x))$.